# Matrix Exponential for two similar matrices

Tags: python, scipy

I have constructed two matrices. For one I calculate matrix exponential, but for the other one I can not. They are similarly constructed and have the same structure and dimension. I really don't know why one can work but the other can not. I put my code below.

```
import numpy as np
import math as math
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
from scipy.sparse.linalg import *

sigmax = [[0, 1], [1, 0]]
sigmay = [[0, -1j], [1j, 0]]
sigmaz = [[1, 0], [0, -1]]
sigmaxx = np.kron(sigmax,sigmax)
sigmayy = np.kron(sigmay,sigmay)
sigmazz = np.kron(sigmaz,sigmaz)
sigmaxxyy = np.mat(sigmaxx) + np.mat(sigmayy)
N = 6

Hxxyy = 0
for i in range (0,N-2+1):
    Hxxyy = np.mat(Hxxyy) + np.mat(np.kron(np.kron(np.identity(2**i),2*np.mat(sigmaxxyy)),np.identity(2**(N-i-2)) ))
Hxxyy = np.mat(Hxxyy) + np.mat(np.kron(np.kron(2*np.mat(sigmax),np.identity(2**(N-2))),sigmax))+np.mat(np.kron(np.kron(2*np.mat(sigmay),np.identity(2**(N-2))),sigmay))   
print(expm(Hxxyy))

Hhi = 0
for j in range (0,N-1+1):
    Hhi = np.mat(Hhi) + np.mat(np.kron( np.kron(np.identity(2**j),3*np.mat(sigmaz)),np.identity(2**(N-1-j))) )
print(expm(Hhi))
```

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new test.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(expm(Hhi))
  File "/Users/sherlock/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py", line 582, in expm
    return _expm(A, use_exact_onenorm='auto')
  File "/Users/sherlock/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py", line 637, in _expm
    X = _fragment_2_1(X, h.A, s)
  File "/Users/sherlock/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py", line 755, in _fragment_2_1
    X[k, k] = exp_diag[k]
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: @VBB I have added the error message. Basically, the problem is that I can not calculate expm(Hhi). But expm(Hxxyy) works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works in Python3 (Python 3.4.5) but fails in Python2 (Python 2.7.12).

There were a few changes in `scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py` between these two versions that cleaned all code paths to support both dense and sparse matrices.

Since the dimensions are not very big, a quick fix would be to
replace

```
 expm(Hhi)
```

with

```
 expm(np.array(Hhi))
```

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded Python3 and it works perferctly

Comment: @JoeJackJessieJames You should [accept his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/306038) since it worked for you :)